# Jquery Slide Up issue

Tags: jquery, hide, slideup

So my script works but the issue I am having is that when i use the close-but function it hides the div, but after a few seconds the div slidesdown. Am I missing something with like a if statement? Thank you.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".cart").hover(function() {
        $(".dropcart").slideDown('slow');
     });
    $('.dropcart').mouseleave(function() {
        $('.dropcart').css({
            'opacity': '.5'
        }, setTimeout(function() {
            $('.dropcart').slideUp('slow');
        }, 3000));
         });
    $('.dropcart').mouseenter(function() {
        $('.dropcart').css({
            'opacity': '1'
        });
    });
        $('.close-but').click( function() {
    $('.dropcart').hide();
    });
    });
```

Comment: Hard to say without seeing more of your code. Maybe you could set up a fiddle? But I'm guessing the problem is that you are hovering over `.cart` causing the `.dropcart` to reappear. You need to either add some logic if the aim is that it shouldn't reappear after the `.close-bit` click (e.g. use a bool flag to store that state) or remove the `.cart` hover behavior when it's no longer needed.

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle. Thank you for the help. http://jsfiddle.net/cornelas/NyduX/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hover` is a shorthand for the `mouseenter/mouseleave` handlers (see: http://api.jquery.com/hover/).

I tend not to use hover for more complex interactions since, as you've discovered, there are some quirks to how the event handler works. I've found that binding an event handler to `hover` fires the handler twice. Instead, what you should do is:

```
$('.cart').mouseenter( function(){
    // Your state behaviour code here..
} ).mouseleave( function(){
    // Your state behaviour code here...
} );
```

One think you might want to consider using is jquery's livequery plugin, which improves event binding/handling for DOM elements. So, your example could be refactored to look something like this:

**Edits:**
Changed pathing to find the parent element that contains both `.cart` and `.dropcart`

```
$('.cart').livequery( function(){
    var obj      = $( this ).closest('.float-left'); // The cart container element
    var dropcart = obj.find('.dropcart'); // Child of .float-left
    var close    = dropcart.find('.close-but');  // Child of dropcart

    // Handle cart mouseenter event
    obj.mouseenter( function(){
        dropcart.slideDown(300);
    } );

    // Handle cart moseenter/mouseleave events
    dropcart.mouseenter( function(){
        // your behaviour here...
    } ).mouseleave( function(){
        // your behaviour here...
        // Read up on jQuery's delay() method: http://api.jquery.com/delay/
        dropcart.delay(800).slideUp(256);
    } );

    // Handle the close button
    close.click( function(){
        dropcart.hide(); // or dropcart.mouseleave(); // triggers the mouseleave event handler
    } );

} );
```

### Update

I didn't see the fiddle in the initial comments, and now that I understand the structure, I've revised the examples above to reflect (see revisions above). A couple additional things I would also recommend doing:

1. Add an ID or common class to the containing element, e.g.
   `class="cart-container float-left"` or `id="cart-container"`
2. Consider refactoring the markup to be a little more semantic considering the content that appears in there. (I know some folks would argue that there's little value in doing that with JS enhanced features, but I still think it's a good habit to get into).

An example of the html refactoring would be:

```
<div class="item-container right">
    <img src="http://news.worldwild.org/wp-content/uploads/2008/09/red_panda.jpg">

    <div class="cart-items">
        <h3>Cart Items: <span class="cart-items-count">10</span></h3>
        <div class="dropcart">
            <dl class="cart-items-list">
                <dt>Items:</dt>
                <dd>10</dd>
                <dt>Price:</dt>
                <dd>$5.00</dd>
            </dl>
            <a href="#" class="close" title="close">x</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>​
```

**Supporting CSS:**

```
.right {
    float: right;
}

.item-container > img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0; padding :0; 
    border: 0;

    width: 100px; height: auto;
}

.item-container .cart-items {
    display: block;
    background: #222;
    color: #fff;
}

.cart-items {
    display: block;
    margin: 0; padding :0; 
}

.cart-items > h3 {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.cart-items-list dt {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    clear: right;
}

.cart-items-list dd {
        text-align: right;
}

.dropcart .close {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 10px;

    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: right;

    color: #fff;
}​
```

Your jQuery script would be something like:

```
jQuery( function(){

    $('.item-container').livequery( function(){
        var obj      = $( this ).find('.cart-items'); // The cart container element
        var dropcart = obj.find('.dropcart'); // Child of .float-left
        var close    = dropcart.find('.close');  // Child of dropcart

        dropcart.hide();

        // Handle cart mouseenter event
        obj.mouseenter( function(){
            dropcart.slideDown(300);
        } );

        // Handle cart moseenter/mouseleave events
        dropcart.mouseenter( function(){
            // your behaviour here...
        } ).mouseleave( function(){
            // your behaviour here...
            // Read up on jQuery's delay() method: http://api.jquery.com/delay/
            dropcart.slideUp(256);
        } );

        // Handle the close button
        close.click( function(){
            dropcart.mouseleave( function(e){ return false; }); // triggers the mouseleave event handler
            dropcart.hide();
        } );

    } );

} );
​
```

You can see it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/kwbbh/2/ (forked the OPs fiddle)
    ​

Comment: But the hover handler is bound to a different element than the mouseenter/mouseleave handler.

Comment: I will take a look at the plugin, but for now mouseenter works better than hover. Thanks you!

Comment: @MattBurland, I don't actually know what the element structure looks like, I can only guess based on his code. I'm assuming that `.dropcart` and `.close-but` are child elements to `.cart`. If a `hover` handler is attached to a parent element, and that parent element loses focus when mousing over a child element, the `mouseleave` event is triggered (on the parent element) when using `hover`. That's why plugins like **hoverIntent** exist (btw, drop-down menus are a good example of that weird behaviour when using the 'hover' event.)

Comment: @user916011: The OP posted a fiddle. `.dropcart` and `.close-but` are not children of `.cart`

Comment: Updated the answer to reflect the OP's original markup, and added an example for refactoring for reusability.

Answer (score 0):

I can't quite see the behavior you describe, but one thing that strikes me is on your mouseleave you are setting a setTimeout. This setTimeout will fire in 3 seconds unless you clear it. So what I do see happening is that you can mouse in to `.dropcart`, then mouse out setting the opacity to 0.5 and setting the timer. Then, if you mouse back into the `.dropcart`, the opacity goes back to 1, but the `.dropcart` still slides up when the timer fires. If you keep mousing in and out of the `.dropcart` you could end up setting a bunch of timers that will fire at seemingly random intervals and really mess up your user experience.

What you need to do is when you do `setTimeout` it returns a timeoutID. You need to store this in a variable so you can pass it to `clearTimeout` when you decide you want to cancel the timeout. For example:

```
var timerID = 0;

$('.dropcart').mouseleave(function() {
    $('.dropcart').css({
        'opacity': '.5'
    });
    if (timerID)
        clearTimeout(timerID);        // stop multiple timers running at once!
    timerID = setTimeout(function() {
        $('.dropcart').slideUp('slow');
        }, 3000));
    });
$('.dropcart').mouseenter(function() {
    if (timerID)
        clearTimeout(timerID);
    $('.dropcart').css({
        'opacity': '1'
    });
});
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NyduX/4/)